# Ansible playbook command gives error while installing phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, ansible

I've ansible playbook and inside that there are multiple commands. Out of those commands below one gives me error.

**command: "npm install phantomjs chdir=projects/phoenix-switch"**

the error is:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use full path to /phoenix-switch against relative?

Comment: Also you can use -vvvvv flag to get verbose information from ansible.

Comment: Hey @rootatdarkstar my silly mistake. I had not installed node. Thank You

Comment: Naturally, if you're using `command` or `shell`, you should seriously consider using a built-in module. In this case it's [the appropriately-named `npm` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/npm_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check the system PATH and check the ansible PATH, because there is differences. 
Try it:

```
- shell: echo $PATH
  register: check

- debug: msg="{{check}} and {{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

It is possible the ansible doesn't see the npm in the `ansible_env.PATH`.